# No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the app.config file

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a problem with my project, I always get the following error:

'No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file'

I have found a lot of solutions but they don't work for me, that's why I have created this topic. I think the error lies in project's hierarchy:

I have 3 projects in my project-folder:

Data_Layer (Class library) which has the ADO.NET project (Entity Framework 6)

Business_Layer (Class library) for all my business logic which references to 'Data_Layer'

Presentation_Layer (WPF project) which holds all views

I have copied the app.config from Data_Layer to all other projects without any success...

This error appears in my Presentation_Layer (XAML) where I instantiate a ViewModel from Business_Layer

```
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:Business_Layer.Windows.Customer;assembly=Business_Layer"
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CustomerAddWindow x:Key="CustomerAddWindow"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

In my Business_Layer, I have different folders e.g 'Customers' (where the viewModels for customers are located). The app.config isn't in any folder. Therefore, I think that's the problem but I don't know or have any idea how to could fix it.

**EDIT:** I have solved my problem by adding the needed EF-references to all projects and just copied the  in all app.config.

Comment: Reread the error message. Do you have a connectionstring named MyEntities in your app.config file for the main project? (Remember that this file is renamed as yourapp.exe.config in the run folder (bin\debug)

Comment: Do you have in the app.config of your wpf application a connectionstring named MyEntities?

Comment: Yes I have. I have copied the content from Data_Layer's app.config to all other project's app.config

Comment: Check the MyApp.exe.config file in the bin folder too please.

Comment: Can you add your app.config sample code here to help the readers answer your question.

Comment: I have fixed it, you can read it in my 'edit' paragraph

Comment: Could you add the _edit_ as an answer so that people know it's been solved (and accept it in two days)?